# AndEngine GLES2- IndexOutOfBoundsException inside Entity.java line: 1402

Tags: android, andengine

I have following errors which I have no idea about:

```
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 0
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:1402)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:284)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:1167)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateScene(Engine.java:591)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:586)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
06-08 19:59:54.367: E/AndroidRuntime(11629):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

I believe it's something related with the onManagedUpdate() inside a MoveModifier I used inside my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost always due to detaching entities in the wrong thread.  Check for anywhere that you might be detaching entities in response to a user interaction, or in a Modifier callback, and wrap it in `runOnUpdateThread`.  E.g.:

```
@Override
public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
    engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            widget.detachSelf();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If I can't detach it onModifierFinished then where else can I detach it? I am actually changing the scene onModifierFinished. Any ideas?

Comment: You can detach it in onModifierFinished as long as you wrap it in "runOnUpdateThread" as in my example.  This works fine because it doesn't run the detach in the current thread - instead it tells the "update thread" to execute it as soon as it can.

Comment: The reason this fixes things is that it allows the update thread to ensure that the scene changes aren't happening when it's in the middle of iterating over the scene.  If you do the detach outside of the update thread, then you run the risk of doing it while the update thread is looping through an array containing that entity and triggering an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - exactly what happened to you.